# Store just one column as foreign key in another entity

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm beginner in java spring boot. I want to store just one column as a part of foreign key instead of complete object. I'm using @ManyToOne annotation.
Now the object looks like
[initialObjectStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo9Me.png). And I want it to look like [finalObjectStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP08U.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What have you tried so far? Show your code and tell us where exactly you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "topic_id")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"name", "description"})
private Topic topic;
```

and you must to add this dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Hope work for you